# Batch file to Copy particular lines from one text file to another text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, copy

I am very new to batch scripting. I don't have much knowledge about Batch Scripting.

My doubt is how to copy only some line from text file to other text file.

Say my File.txt is

```
This is sample file.
I want copy this line.
Also this line.
But not this line.
```

I want to copy line 2 and 3, but not using their line number, because may change.

This muchI have done till now:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET InFile=abc.txt
SET OutFile=Output.txt
IF EXIST "%OutFile%" DEL "%OutFile%"
SET TempFile=Temp.txt
IF EXIST "%TempFile%" DEL "%TempFile%"

IF EXIST "%OutFile%" DEL "%OutFile%"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR "I want" "%InFile%"') DO (
    ECHO.%%A> "%TempFile%"
    ECHO.%TempFile%>>"%OutFile%"
REM CALL :RemovePrecedingWordA "%%A"
    )
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR " Also this" "%InFile%"') DO (
    ECHO.%%A> "%TempFile%"
    ECHO.%TempFile%>>"%OutFile%"
REM CALL :RemovePrecedingWordA "%%A"
    )
```

But its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the /g: option to findstr, basically do

```
findstr /g:pattern.txt %InFile% > %OutFile%
```

where pattern.txt is (in your example)

```
I want
Also this
```

This assumes you can write `findstr` regular expressions for all the lines you want to copy.

If you use findstr with multiple files (wildcard) you will get the file name prepended. To get round this, use

`del out.txt
for %F in (*.txt); do findstr /g:pattern.txt %F >> out.txt`

Note that you should put the source files in a different directory to the pattern and output files (or use a different extension) otherwise the `*.txt` wildcard will pick those files up, too.

Comment: Hi Peter, is there any way to remove the file path while using wildcard "c:\*.txt". My output will show "c:\test.txt: Blablabla" rather than "Blablabla". Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Nyc2x not straightforward but see the edit to my post - is that what you mean? Otherwise, asking a new question might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) for this purpose. Certain lines (in this case 2 and 3) are copied as follows:

```
sed -n -e 2p -e 3p input.txt > output.txt
```

If you wish to copy a segment of lines (all lines from line 2 to line 10) then you may use:

```
sed -n -e 2,10p input.txt > output.txt
```

Or you can also use combinations of certain lines and segments:

```
sed -n -e 2,10p -e 15p -e 27p input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: the question states: "but not using their line number, because may change."