# Cut one line from a txt file and insert it into a new one using batch command

Tags: batch-file

I know pretty much nothing about batch programming and I would like to do the following thing.

I have a .txt file that could have one or several lines and I would like to cut the last line and insert it into another .txt file. I have been doing some research before asking this question but I couldn't find anything "understandable" to me in order to achieve this.

Also, the most appropriate QA found, was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280827/batch-file-to-copy-particular-lines-from-one-text-file-to-another-text-file) link on Stack but I don't know how to "translate" it.

**This are my lines within the .txt file**

```
S,1,______,_,__;Cutii carton 370*290*2;1.00;1.000;1;1;1;0;0;
T,1,______,_,__;0;1.00;;;;
```

I would like to cut the line starting with "T" from this .txt file and insert into a new .txt file.

Could anyone help me? Thanks

**EDIT**

Please see the [print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X99r0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the last (non-empty) line from a text file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (ttt.txt) do set last=%%A
```

appending it to another file:

```
echo %last%>>ttt_lastline.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('Find /C /V ""^<"%~1"') Do @Set/A _=%%A-1
@(More +%_% "%~1")>"%~dpn1_lastline.txt"
```

Just drag and drop your text file onto the batch file and the last non empty line will be output into a text document in the same directory as the dropped file. The output file will have the same name as the dropped file but with `_lastline` appended to the end.

**[Edit]**
If you want to hard code the file name then:

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('Find /C /V ""^<"File.txt"') Do @Set/A _=%%A-1
@(More +%_% "File.txt")>"File_lastline.txt"
```

You may prefer the following method although it will likely be slower especially as `File.txt` gets larger:

```bat
@For /F "UseBackDelims=" %%A In ("File.txt") Do @Set "last=%%A"
@(Echo %last%)>"File_lastline.txt"
```

Comment: This works. But let's say the end user won't be able to drag and drop the file over the batch command, but only to call the batch command that will extract the last line, through an external program.

Comment: `%~1` is the input file, if you're running the batch script with a filename argument then it will still work as designed. `"MyBatch.cmd" "C:\Users\cdrrrr\Desktop\testfile.txt"` If you're not running the script like that then unless you provide that information, I cannot tell you how to adapt things to suit you.

Comment: `@For /F %%A In ('Find /C /V ""^<"ttt.txt"') Do @Set/A _=%%A-1
@(More +%_% "ttt.txt")>"%~dpn1_lastline.txt"` - like this?

Comment: I have added an Edit to give an example based upon the comment above!

Comment: It's not working man. I have the file ttt.txt where I have the above two lines, the `MyBatch.cmd` with the code you provided and the output ttt_lastline.txt which is empty after the bat is runned, even though in the column "Date Modified" the indicator for minutes is changing...

And all files are in the same directory.

Comment: I have added a print screen

Comment: I have updated the hard coded version to match the new file name you appear to be using. The version shown in your `Print Screen` was incorrect because you changed something for no reason whatsoever and it broke the batch file output. Either `%%T` should read `%%A` or `%%A` should read `%%T`, *they should both match* each other.

Comment: @cdrrrr, I really must thank you for choosing someone elses slower solution which could be improved, _(and was in my own response)_. I really hope you're satisfied with allowing me to edit answers according to your comments, report to you the issues you created yourself and even creating a video to show you that my code did work despite your reports to the contrary. My answer is better than that you have now selected and you haven't even bothered to apologise for your errors, thank me for the effort I put in and report back that my solutions do actually work.

Answer (score 0):

To cut the first "n" lines of several files and concatenate them sequentially into one, you can use:

```
For %f in (list-filename*.txt) do more +n(number of lines to be removed) > type >> Outputfilename.txt %f
```